# Why switching cause EMI & noise problem?

Tags: power-supply, basic, inductive

I was reading an article topic on "[Selecting the correct IC for power supply applications](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt259/slyt259.pdf)" in which it tells the different types of topology and their pros and cons.In that, it list out the three types of topologies and one of them is **inductive switching**.

At the end he writes

`The switching converter also causes electromagnetic interference (EMI) radiation from
the inductor and noise on the output due to the switching.`

So my question is which things are responsible for these interference. Which type of **switcher** is he talking about? It's a little bit complicated for me to understand.I even search it on web but didn't get any document that helps me.

Comment: Switching converters use switching elements (MOSFET's) to convert the current and voltage from low to high or vice versa.These MOSFET's will be driven with very high rise times, which leads to high(1/pi*tr) frequencies, more problems will occur if these switching currents flow in a big loop. there is an input loop and output loop whose area should be minimised.

Answer (score 3):

EMI in power supplies can come from multiple sources, including:

- Capacitive currents driven by switching voltages
- E-fields produced by switching voltages
- Stray H-fields from high di/dt loops and inductors/transformers
- High-frequency rectification

The article cites three classifications of converters:

- Linear regulators
- Charge pumps
- Inductive switcher

Linear regulators are step-down converters (input higher than output) which work by dissipating power to achieve regulation, usually in a non-saturated series pass element like a transistor or MOSFET. There is no high-frequency switching going on, so the circuit from an EMI perspective is incredibly quiet.

Charge pumps are switched-capacitor sources, where energy is stored in a capacitor, the capacitor is disconnected from the source and reconnected quickly in such a way to provide a 'boost' of voltage. There is switching going on but in general, they are for extremely low power levels (a few watts at most) and generally are extremely compact in terms of physical layout, so they don't contribute much to EMI (when done well).

What the article means by 'inductive switcher' is a switching power supply that uses inductors as energy storage devices, which comprises the vast majority of power supplies commonly available today. Buck converters, boost converters, flyback converters, half-bridge and full-bridge converters, Cuks and SEPICs - these are all "inductive switchers" and all involve converting DC into high-frequency AC, manipulating the average value (through duty cycle and other means) then rectifying the AC back into DC. You'll see all of my previously cited EMI sources come into play in these converters.

The science behind EMI is incredibly complex, and takes a large amount of theoretical knowledge and 'hands-on' experience to really grasp. It's not something that can be explained properly in a few paragraphs. Just keep in mind that any high-frequency switching (10s of kilohertz or higher) will likely induce EMI that will need to be dealt with somehow, and (in general) the higher the power level, the worse the EMI can be. EMI is also largely influenced by parasitic elements and physical component placement - a bad layout for a 10W converter can cause bigger EMI problems than a nicely-done 100W converter.

Comment: In inductive switcher you write "and all involve converting DC into high-frequency AC, manipulating the average value (through duty cycle and other means) then rectifying the AC back into DC." What that means I didn't get this point.Could you please explain a little bit more about this.

Comment: so to aviod EMI in a circuit,techniques that are adopted are shielding ,EMI filtering etc. Shielding all the parisitic components are quite complex and uneconomical so for EMI filtering, using Y rated cap are good enough or should I choose another thing?

Comment: You need to manage parasitics by doing a careful layout, and filter EMI through a variety of techniques (common and differential mode filtering using inductors and capacitors, shielding, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the article meant with **inductive switching** since I can only find some proximity sensor, clearly not related with power supply application.

It's likely it was referring to some kind of [SMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) (switched-mode power supply), where different kind of transistor (like MOSFETs or BJTs) are used in [saturation zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor#Transistor_as_a_switch).

EMI problems arise for two different causes:

1. Electronic switches are controlled at very high frequencies, thus generating high frequency alternated currents, which, as a consequence, can lead to emitting elettromagnetic waves.
2. When commuting from on to off state, several effects arise inside the transistor wich could lead to impulsive currents.

To avoid such effects manifacturers suggest:

1. Using varying frequency to control the transistor
2. Add a snubber circuit to your design

Comment: I meant to TOPOLOGY(I have already mentioned it in my question).